# How to set list to multi-level column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have Lat and Lon coordinates for 5 cities. The coordinates are stored in lists named 'City_1_lat_list', 'City_1_lon_list', and so on...

My longest list is 2589 elements long, hence the index range value. I thought I would be able to set the values to the df by assigning the list to the column name ex: `df['City_1']['Lon'] = City_1_lon_list`. I also tried converting the list to a Pandas series `df['City_1']['Lon'] = pd.Series(City_1_lon_list)`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

arrays = [
        ["City_1", "City_1", "City_2", "City_2", "City_3", "City_3", "City_4", "City_4", "City_5", "City_5"],
        ["Lon", "Lat", "Lon", "Lat", "Lon", "Lat", "Lon", "Lat", "Lon", "Lat"]]
    tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(2589), columns=index[:10])
```

Is there a way to set a list to a multi-level column in a dataframe without looping through the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set tuples with `pd.Series`, because different length of lists:

```
df[('City_1', 'Lon')] = pd.Series(City_1_lon_list)
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't quite understand the difference between `df[('City_1', 'Lon')]` and `df['City1']['Lon']`

Comment: @rastawolf -  Because chained indexing, better it is explained [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)